# Lottery program in python from Y Daniel Liang

Tags: python

I am new to python. The following is a practice programming exercise from Y Daniel Liang Python book Chapter 4.
if the lottery number is 333, am getting perfect match for different user inputs such as 133, 233, 433, 533, 633, 733, 833, 933, I have no idea why.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

#import random

lottery = 333  #random.randint(100, 999)
guess = int(input("\nEnter a three-digit number: "))
print("\nThe Lottery Number is:", lottery)

lottery_digit1 = lottery // 100
lottery %= 100
lottery_digit2 = lottery // 10
lottery_digit3 = lottery % 10

guess_digit1 = guess // 100
guess %= 100
guess_digit2 = guess // 10
guess_digit3 = guess % 10

if guess == lottery:
    print("Perfect Match: First Prize $10,000")
elif (guess_digit1 == lottery_digit1 or
      guess_digit1 == lottery_digit2 or
      guess_digit1 == lottery_digit3) and \
    (guess_digit2 == lottery_digit1 or
     guess_digit2 == lottery_digit2 or
     guess_digit2 == lottery_digit3) and \
    (guess_digit3 == lottery_digit1 or
     guess_digit3 == lottery_digit2 or
     guess_digit3 == lottery_digit3):
    print("Matching All Digits: Second Prize $3,000")
elif (guess_digit1 == lottery_digit1 or
      guess_digit1 == lottery_digit2 or
      guess_digit1 == lottery_digit3) or \
    (guess_digit2 == lottery_digit1 or
     guess_digit2 == lottery_digit2 or
     guess_digit2 == lottery_digit3) or \
    (guess_digit3 == lottery_digit1 or
     guess_digit3 == lottery_digit2 or
     guess_digit3 == lottery_digit3):
    print("Matching a Single Digit: Third Prize $1,000")
else:
    print("Nice Try.")
```

Comment: Is this from a textbook on how to write spaghetti code?

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are getting a match when the last two digits are the same is becasue of these lines here:

```
lottery %= 100
...
guess %= 100
```

you are changing the values of both lottery and guess. 
the `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=` and `%=` operators change the value of the variable they are used on. so after you do this operation your variables become:

```
lottery =333
lottery %= 100
#lottery is now 33
```

and

```
guess = 733
guess %= 100
#guess is now 33
```